# How to ignore invalid inputs or add try except code in the sorted function?

Tags: python, lambda, sorting

I want to sort list of dictionary according to date.

Following code is working fine where my data format is fix i.e. dd/mm/yyyy

**Code:**

```
[{'date': '10/10/2015'},
 {'date': '11/10/2015'},
 {'date': '01/01/2015'},
 {'date': '10/12/2014'},
 {'date': '01/01/2014'},
 {'date': '2015'}]

In [20]: a.pop()
Out[20]: {'date': '2015'}

In [21]: sorted(a, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x['date'], "%d/%m/%Y"), reverse=False)
Out[21]: 
[{'date': '01/01/2014'},
 {'date': '10/12/2014'},
 {'date': '01/01/2015'},
 {'date': '10/10/2015'},
 {'date': '11/10/2015'}]
```

But in I also have date value which not match with dd/mm/yyyy format.
Get following exception:

**Code2:**

```
In [22]: a.append({"date":"2015"})

In [23]: sorted(a, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x['date'], "%d/%m/%Y"), reverse=False)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-abd07eed54eb> in <module>()
----> 1 sorted(a, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x['date'], "%d/%m/%Y"), reverse=False)

<ipython-input-23-abd07eed54eb> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 sorted(a, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x['date'], "%d/%m/%Y"), reverse=False)

/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
    323     if not found:
    324         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
--> 325                          (data_string, format))
    326     if len(data_string) != found.end():
    327         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %

ValueError: time data '2015' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'

In [24]:
```

**How to handle such inputs in `sorted` function??**

Answer (score 2):

Our data:

```
In [51]: a = [{'date': '10/10/2015'},
   ....:  {'date': '11/10/2015'},
   ....:  {'date': '01/01/2015'},
   ....:  {'date': '10/12/2014'},
   ....:  {'date': '01/01/2014'},
   ....:  {'date': '2015'}]
```

First remove wrong date from `a`

```
In [52]: a = [i for i in a if len(i['date'])>9]
```

Second:

```
In [53]: sorted(a, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x['date'], "%d/%m/%Y"), reverse=False)
Out[53]: 
[{'date': '01/01/2014'},
 {'date': '10/12/2014'},
 {'date': '01/01/2015'},
 {'date': '10/10/2015'},
 {'date': '11/10/2015'}]
```

You can write it to one line:

```
sorted([i for i in a if len(i['date'])>9], key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x['date'], "%d/%m/%Y"), reverse=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, but  `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 2):

one option is to handle exceptions in the key function:

```
def custom_sort(x):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(x['date'], "%d/%m/%Y")
    except ValueError:
        # do something else if the date format is different
    except KeyError:
        # do something else if there is no 'date' key in x
        # ...

sorted(a, key=custom_sort)
```

or you can use `if-else` constructs to convert the data to the correct format before applying datetime functions...

---

**edit**: here are 2 bit more practical options:

```
a = [{'date': '05/06/2017'}, {'ff': 2016}, {'date': 2015}, {'date': '05/06/2014'}, 'ff']

def sort_by_converting_to_strings(x):
    try:
        return str(datetime.datetime.strptime(x['date'], "%d/%m/%Y"))
    except (KeyError, ValueError, TypeError):
        try:
            return str(x['date'])
        except (KeyError, TypeError):
                return str(x)
print sorted(a, key=sort_by_converting_to_strings)
# [{'date': '05/06/2014'}, {'date': 2015}, {'date': '05/06/2017'}, 'ff', {'ff': 2016}]


def validate(x):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(x['date'], "%d/%m/%Y")
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False
print sorted([i for i in a if validate(i)])
# [{'date': '05/06/2014'}, {'date': '05/06/2017'}]
```

of course you can combine the approaches to get a solution suited for your particular use case...

Comment: Up Voted +1 Yes, I also created function which return only valid date format to sorted function. i.e. pre processing on input list. Is there is any way in sorted function to ignore such input items.?

Comment: `custom_sort` is applied during execution of the `sorted` function in the same fashion as an anonymous lambda, it is not pre-processing the input list, i.e. it is not updating any values... or what exactly do you need plz?

Comment: also what do yo mean by `ignore`? you can either remove those items from output list, put them to the beginning, to the end or arbitrarily mix with other items - but if you remove them, the sorted list won't have the same length of the original list...